# How to save a file in a specific directory in java?

Tags: java, file, directory, java-io

My Client class receives a file from Server and wants to save it in a specific directory. Here is my Code

```
   Object object=sInput.readObject();
   if(object instanceof fileDetail){
       fileDetail obj1= (fileDetail)object;
       String str= "A "+obj1.fileExtension+" Received From "+obj1.source;
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,str,"Success", WIDTH, null);
   }
```

fileDetail is a Serializable object that I'm using to manage the packate received from Server.Here is the class fileDetail

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.Serializable;


public class fileDetail implements Serializable{
    public File file;
    public String fileExtension;
    public String source;
    public String destination;

}
```

Server is selecting files by `JFileChooser` and any kind of file may be chosen. The chosen file is saved in a `fileDetail` class object and that object is sent to client .Now that I get received file from `obj1.file` in client code ; I want to save it to a specific Directory. How can do this ? I'm kinda noob in Java.

Comment: If you are using Java 1.7 : You want to use Files: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html If you are not using Java 1.7 you want to use apache-commons-io (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) or google guava (https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). You also could do it manually.

Comment: Thanks for you help. How can I do it manually ? Can please be a bit elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

Ask user for input of the file path. Take the path and simply use it to print the object data in it. If the path is absolute than use it or else file will be created in current directory. You can provide this info while prompting user for file path.

Comment: "simply use it to print the object data in it" 
Can you please tell a bit elaborately how can I do this?

Comment: Override toString() method in fileDetail class. Then you can simply do `BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("Path To File")));
writer.write(writer.toString());`